# Problem with css backgroundImage property for local image in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem with CSS `backgroundImage` property for local image in Angular JS

Hello everyone,
I to make my `<footer>` element in angular component i use next expression:

```html
<footer
  class='footerline'
  [ngStyle]="{'backgroundImage':'url(https://i.postimg.cc/zGbSDdFB/footer.jpg)','width':'1280px','height':'100px'}" >
</footer>`
```

Image painted element `<footer>` correctly - there is no problems.

When i try to cover `<footer>` using local in app folder based image - full route :"src/app/images/footer.jpg"

I try use next expression:

```html
<footer
  class='footerline'
  [ngStyle]="{'backgroundImage':'url(../src/app/images/footer.jpg)','width':'1280px','height':'100px'}" >
</footer>`
```

It does not work.
Please help me with right syntax or decision.
Thanks everyone

Comment: try ```url(app/images/footer.jpg)``` . Also, It is good practice to put images on the app/assets folder.

Comment: thanks that way is more good, that you answer " app/assets folder "